# HttpGet route not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have built a controller. For some unknown reason the end point is not reached. Unfortunately I do not understand why.

```
[Route("api/realestates")]
[ApiController]
public class RealEstateController : CustomControllerBase<RealEstateController>
{
    [HttpGet]   // not reached
    public async Task<IResult<List<RealEstateListDTO>>> GetAll()
    {
        //[...]
    }
}
```

If i change the route from controller to `api/realestate` or from Get-method to `[HttpGet("all")]` it works. In the CustomControllerBase are no routes defined.

I used autogenerated Swagger to test the route. I have intentionally overwritten the route. The route works, if i don't start with debugger. If i uses the Debbuger, Swagger shows the route but i get the index.html-Fallback.

Comment: Well, what URL are you using to call the method?

Comment: What end point?  Use Postman to diagnose the endpoints your using.  Try [Route("/api/realestates")] if that's the endpoint.  You haven't shown your program so guesswork.

Comment: I think you need this: `[Route("api/[controller]")]` instead of `[Route("api/realestates")]`

Comment: I used autogenerated Swagger to test the route.
I have intentionally overwritten the route. It is like that in the whole project. It just doesn't work for the one.

Comment: My conclusion is that the problem is in the stuff you aren't showing us!

Comment: What do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

check your endpoint in postman or browser
and check your startup has something like this

```
services.AddControllersWithViews
```

or

```
 services.AddControllers
```

and your customecontroller must inherits `ControllerBase`

Comment: I uses `AddControllersWithViews` and ControllerBase. All the other routes in the controller works.

Answer (score 0):

You’re calling ‘api/realestate’

But in the attribute you’ve defined ‘api/realestates’

So try with the ‘s’ at the end

If you want the route to match the controller name (minus “Controller”). You should change your route attribute to -

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```